# Magento 2.4.2 : Reorder issue with product custom option error "The product has required options. Enter the options and try again." on cart Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, reorder

**Preconditions (*)**

1. Magento 2.4.2
2. Reordering an order with products that have required custom options as checkbox type.

**Steps to reproduce (*)**

1. Install and Setup Fresh Magento 2.4.2
2. Create a product with required custom option with input type as **checkbox**
3. Add this product to cart by checking the checkbox and place an order with any payment method.
4. Now click **reorder** link of the same order from the customer dashboard.
5. Customer redirected to cart page with errors "Some of the products below do not have all the required options." and "The product has required options. Enter the options and try again.".

**Expected result (*)**

Products should be added to the shopping cart successfull by automatic selecting custom option.

**Actual result (*)**

Failed to add product in cart with error message("Some of the products below do not have all the required options." and "The product has required options. Enter the options and try again.".

I've found similar [issue](http://2.4-develop) raised in git and it was fixed in M2.4 develop branch. The changes are there in the M2.4.2 but the issue still persist. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.